# Whats is the Ethereum blockchain size?

Tags: chaindata

Another question regarding Ethereum chain size

I downloaded the blockchain with geth in fast mode the weight is 14Go, but i can see on https://etherscan.io/chart2/chaindatasizefast that it is in geth fast mode around 60Go. What size is correct ?

On another site we can see that the full ethereum weight is around 387Go https://bitinfocharts.com/ethereum/
Is this the current Ethereum chain size ?

I am talking about the folder /chaindata not the other folders containing DAG

Comment: Hey. Have you come up with any answers? If so, would you mind sharing here?

Answer (score 1):

You can now use [chainstats](https://chainstats.org/), a page made by [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/), a blockchain infrastructure provider (full disclosure, I'm a dev advocate at Chainstack and worked on this page).

This app displays the current size of all the public network Chainstack support based on the Protocol, node type (full or archive), and blockchain client.

It is automatically updated when the size changes in the resources required by the servers.